# Reassign Variable which is coming as @Input in component

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, frontend, angular11

I have a component which takes a boolean value as @Input. I am controlling a div using ngIf with this value(to show/hide). Now, when I pass value true or false in both cases, the UI shows the div, whereas when not giving anything, it does not. Am I missing something here?

Index.html

```
<abc-comp x="1" y="64" showviewmore="true"></abc-comp>
```

abc-comp.ts

```
  @Input() x = '';
  @Input() y = '';
  @Input() showviewmore : boolean;
```

abc-comp.html

```
  <div class="col-xs-4" *ngIf="showviewmore">
      //Some Content and tags
  </div>
```

Also, I am trying to reassign the value of showviewmore variable in the ngOnInit() method but it never enters the if statement

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
   if(!this.showviewmore){
     this.showviewmore = newValue;
   }
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can always set a default value to @Input  -  @Input() showviewmore = false. And then when there is a change detection, it will get updated. does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showviewmore="true"` passes the value as `string`.
You have to modify `[showviewmore]="true"`

```
<abc-comp x="1" y="64" [showviewmore]="true"></abc-comp>
```